# django CMS don't show toolbar on login

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm looking for a way to not automatically show the CMS toolbar (version 3.3.0) when a 'staff-user' logs in.

The toolbar should only be activated when `?edit` is in the URL.
The [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/reference/configuration.html#cms-toolbar-hide) mentions the `CMS_TOOLBAR_HIDE` option, but I don't see any effects when enabled. Also the description:

> "If True, the toolbar is hidden in the pages out django CMS."

seems not totally clear to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: In our case, when logged in with a staff user, the toolbar is hidden except for the toggle button in the top right corner. Do you want to hide this toggle button, as well, or is your problem that the toolbar is really completely visible, and the toggle button alone would be fine?

Answer (score 3):

If you add `?toolbar_off` to the URL the toolbar disappears completely (no toggle button). `?edit` turns it back on.

To automatically turn it off:

(A) You'd could add something like a middleware or hook into the login chain and add the parameter there.

(B) You might subclass/extend the `CMSToolbar` to override the following default behavior:

```
def init_toolbar(self, request):
    self.request = request
    self.is_staff = self.request.user.is_staff
    self.edit_mode = self.is_staff and self.request.session.get('cms_edit', False)
    self.show_toolbar = self.is_staff or self.request.session.get('cms_edit', False)
    if self.request.session.get('cms_toolbar_disabled', False):
        self.show_toolbar = False
```

Especially the last lines would have to be changed to use a default of `True`:

```
    if self.request.session.get('cms_toolbar_disabled', True):
        self.show_toolbar = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden the `login.html` and adding a trailing `?toolbar_off` to the `{{ next }}` hidden input value.

```
<form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-element-wrapper">
        <input class="form-input" type="text" name="username" autofocus="" maxlength="254"
               required="" id="id_username" data-cip-id="id_username">
        <span class="form-input-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-input-bar"></span>
        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-element-wrapper">
        <input class="form-input [% password_css %]" type="password" name="password" required=""
               id="id_password" data-cip-id="id_password">
        <span class="form-input-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-input-bar"></span>
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Passwort</label>
<!-- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE! -->
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}?toolbar_off"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-element-wrapper">
        <button class="form-element form-button" type="submit"
                value="{% trans 'Log in' %}">{% trans 'Log in' %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Just a little solution if a user signs in via the login page. This does not affect the login via `?edit`.